# c# motorola use datawedge only in textboxes

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola, datawedge

I use datawedge to scan barcodes in my windows mobile c#.net cf application, which works quite nice.

i use a motorola es 400 for my software.

But I have the problem, that datawedge works "everywhere": In the textboxes and also on buttons, lists,...

After the barcode it also sends the return-key and this triggers a button, if focused.

Can I configure datawedge, so it doesn't send return at the end anymore?

I don't want to catch all returns, this button should still work!

*Second possibilty:
If this wouldn't work, how do I catch the barcode button of my es400 (and get the focused control in this event?)*

http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/i/story/30/40/089277/motorola_es400_6.jpg (the one right to the green call button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should start using the motorola SDK (or MDK or how they call it).

The SDK has functions to control the scanner and to get an event when a barcode has been scanned. That will solve all your troubles finding out how to route data that is comming via the keyboard emulation of DataWedge.

If you still want to go with DataWedge you have to set Form.KeyPreview to True and setup the datawedge to use a preamble to distinguish barcode data from typed data. Then in KeyPress/KeyUp or/and KeyDown event of the form check the incoming data and place it in the scan data input where you need it.

But I strongly recommand to use the Motorola SDK.